# Facing errors in running the application of Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Im new to ruby and when try run a application, Im facing the below error

`Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'haml'
gem 'nifty-utils'
gem 'nilify_blanks'
gem 'authie'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'chronic'
gem 'dynamic_form'
gem 'activevalidators'
gem 'bcrypt', '3.1.7'
gem 'rails_env_config'
gem 'chronic_duration'
gem 'datey'
gem 'nifty-attachments'
gem 'puma'
gem 'moonrope'
gem 'florrick'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'foreman'
gem 'redcarpet', '3.5.1'
gem 'premailer'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'annotate'
  gem 'pry-rails'
end
```

**Error:**

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Development/status/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/racc-1.6.1/ext/racc/cparse
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r
./siteconf20221220-32692-ivgdf1.rb extconf.rb
checking for rb_block_call()... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

while running the below command

```
bundle --full-index
```

Comment: That's often a case of trying to install a compiled extension, but your system lacks the compiler tools that are expected. Do you have the command-line tools for your compiler installed? Does `mkmf.log` have any useful details?

Comment: Your version of Ruby is not supported by your version of Rails. You need to use Ruby 1.8.7, 1.9.2, or 1.9.3.

Comment: Also, never use the system Ruby installation. The system Ruby installation is for the system, not for you. Apple explicitly says so in their release notes.